# Can't launch application. dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I built a project in Visual Studio 2017, Windows 7, SDK 10.0.16299.0
I get error when I launch the application.

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

But there is no api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll in my drive. Just -l1-1-0.dll

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Talk to whomever is responsible for Windows Update delivery in your company, tell him that you need the ucrtbase update.  If that is a problem for some reason then consider targeting an older version of the SDK or look in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\ directory for the files.

Comment: What can I do if I work without company?